# Using OWIN with VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, identity, owin

I am trying to set up some password policies, I managed to successfully do this in C#, but I need to convert the code into VB. There are two issues that I cannot figure out:

1) `app.UseUserManagerFactory` does not exist;

It states `UseUserManagerFactory is not a member of Owin.IAppBuilder`

2) The `OnCreate` attribute when instantiating the `Provider` is not being passed correctly

```
Public Sub ConfigureAuth(app As IAppBuilder)
   'Configure the UserManager
   app.UseUserManagerFactory(New IdentityFactoryOptions(Of ApplicationUserManager)() With { _
   .DataProtectionProvider = app.GetDataProtectionProvider(), _
   .Provider = New IdentityFactoryProvider(Of ApplicationUserManager)() With { _
      .OnCreate = ApplicationUserManager.Create _
   } _
})
```

Here is the `Create` function for the sake of completeness:

```
Public Shared Function Create(options As IdentityFactoryOptions(Of ApplicationUserManager))           
   Dim manager = New ApplicationUserManager(New ApplicationUserStore(New ApplicationDbContext()))
   manager.UserValidator = New UserValidator(Of ApplicationUser)(manager) With {.AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = False, .RequireUniqueEmail = True}
   manager.PasswordValidator = New PasswordValidator()

   Dim dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider
   If (dataProtectionProvider IsNot Nothing) Then
      ' Do stuff
   End If

   Return manager
End Function
```

Any help would be appreciated, my VB skills coupled with the lack of documentation has me scratching my head.

Comment: 1) Are you sure you have the correct references and imported all needed namespaces? 2) I think you are looking for `AddressOf` (`.OnCreate = AddressOf ApplicationUserManager.Create`)

Comment: 1) Well I figured it's safe to assume that `UseUserManagerFactory` is in the same namespace as `IAppBuilder` but I will double check tomorrow
2) I was using `.OnCreate = AddressOf ApplicationUserManager.Create` before, can you clarify why the method itself is referenced by address?
Thanks for the response